# Raspberry Pi IPv4 address not visible

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, windows, putty

I had connected my Raspberry Pi 3 with my laptop via a headless connection. I obtained my pi's ipv4 address by using Angry IP Scanner. I performed some mini projects as well. The pi worked fine for about 2 days. After that it my pi's ipv4 address stopped showing. When I ping the hostname 'raspberrypi.mshome.net' from the windows command prompt, it shows request timed out.
I am using Windows 10 as my OS.
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
PuTTy server to connect to it via ssh.
RJ45 ethernet cable.
Please respond asap.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me occasionally, I usually do this process every time i turn my PC on at the start of a new day.

I am assuming your laptop is running windows and is connected to the internet via Wi-Fi.

Turn off your Pi and plug the Ethernet cable in, on your laptop press start and search for and open "Network and Sharing Centre" then press "Change adaptor settings" on the left column. You should have multiple adaptors, one will be called WiFi or WLAN or similar, one will be called Ethernet or LAN or similar. right click on WiFi, click properties then go to sharing tab and untick "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection" and press OK. Then go back into WiFi properties, Sharing tab and tick that box this time and select Ethernet from the drop down box then press OK.

Now go into Ethernet properties, double click the IPV4 entry in the list on the Networking tab and set it the same as mine in the image below:

[image: IPV4 Settings]

Now press OK on that box and on the properties box and turn on the Pi.

Launch command prompt and type

```
arp -a
```

this will display a list of all IP and MAC addresses connected to your PC. One will start with 192.168.137.XXX and will have the MAC address of your Pi, SSH into that IP address.

Once you have done this once you only need to do the untick and retick the sharing box step whenever you reboot your PC, the IP address will stay assigned otherwise between RasPi reboots.

Comment: This did not work. I am somehow having the same issue. Is there any other way through which I can work this out?